# Getting MacOS Preview to play audio by \href{run: in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref, mac, audio

Originally I had a file `audio.mp4` that I wanted to play by `\href{run:audio.mp4}{START}` from a `beamer` presentation pdf that is run in Preview. Following hints here, I created a `.app` by `appify`, and it works: entering `open runit.app`  at the terminal prompt now runs the audio fine. However, `\href{run:runit.app}{START}` still doesn't work (I tried all minor 
syntactic variants, with absolute path, `./runit.app`, `\href[]{`   and so forth).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Two things to check: If you double click on `runnit.app` in `Finder`, does the app work and play the audio file? Second, you need to open the PDF file with a reader such as `Acrobat` that supports click able links for external applications. I don't think `Preview` supports this.

Comment: Dear Peter, `runit.app` will start fine from `Finder`. My primary interest is running audio from Preview, I'm not ready to install `Acrobat` for security/bloat reasons. Since `media9` and other packages seem to have the same limitation, I'm more or less ready to give up on this and suffer the indignity of pushing an external  button during my presentation. Thanks anyway, learning about `appify` was worth it in and of itself.